# Will Changing App Bundle name in next update make any issue?

Tags: android, android-app-bundle

I wanna change my Android App name not only that name that appears on Play Store but also the bundle name but of course i won't change the package name that com.xxx.xxx but only the Bundle name that name that Appears on the User Device, will the users be able to update the app or it will say that there is another app with the same package name?

Comment: Please it is important, i am a deaf and i don't have any other work and i live from the little money that i get from admob :(

Comment: I can't find an answer for the question online, and i wanna change the Bundle name in next uodate but in meantime i don't need to lose the current 2500 users :(

Comment: For example if WhatsApp changed their App Bundle name to HelloApp without changing the package name com.wahstapp.whatsapp , will users be able to update or the system will say there is another app on your device with the same package name? also will auto update work or not?

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski Do you know the Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not going to alter `packageId` specified in your application manifest file of your application then you are safe. This, along with the certificate used to sign the release is the only thing that matters.

What is shown to the users (like names under icons on their launcher) are just text labels (which can also be different depending on used localization) and as such are irrelevant from upgrade perspective. Application `packageId` must be unique (and this is enforced by Google Play), labels shown under icons can be anything.

See [App Manifest Overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro), then [Package name and application](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro#package-name) and other related docs.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem updating any thing inside the application including App name itself with the same Package name, and your users will be able to install updates, but it's not a good Idea to change the app name because this may confuse your users.